# Error while appending collected tweets to a list

Tags: python, json, twitter, tweepy

Trying to store the content of the tweets collected into the data list.
But encountering an error I am not sure how to fix.

Code:

```
data=[]

import json

def string_to_json(line):
    import ast
    jsonval=ast.literal_eval(line)
    return jsonval

with open('tweetFile.json', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        line=string_to_json(line)
        print(line['full_text'])
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-30-5e3ff09bab03> in <module>
     10         line=string_to_json(line)
     11         print(line['full_text'])
---> 12         data.append(json.loads(line))

~\anaconda3\lib\json\__init__.py in loads(s, cls, object_hook, parse_float, parse_int, parse_constant, object_pairs_hook, **kw)
    339     else:
    340         if not isinstance(s, (bytes, bytearray)):
--> 341             raise TypeError(f'the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, '
    342                             f'not {s.__class__.__name__}')
    343         s = s.decode(detect_encoding(s), 'surrogatepass')

TypeError: the JSON object must be str, bytes or bytearray, not dict
```

Answer (score 0):

`json.loads()` can directly load a string:

```
data=[]
import json

with open('tweetFile.json', encoding = 'utf-8') as f1:
    for line in f1:
        #print(line['full_text'])
        data.append(json.loads(line))
```

Comment: The problem is that doesn't work for some reason. I get this error: `JSONDecodeError: Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 1 column 2 (char 1)`